# Optimal sampling strategy when only marginal group sizes are known

Tags: sampling, marginal-distribution, stratification

I seems to me that this cannot be such an uncommon situation but I find I cannot come up with the answer myself and I also cannot come up with the correct search terms to find it, either here on Cross Validated or on on the internet more general.

The (toy version of the) problem statement is this: I want to take a representative sample from a population which consists of units with certain (discrete) properties. Let's say they can be red or green, and they can be big or small. However, I only know the marginal distribution of these properties in the population*, not the cell proportions. Let''s say the marginal proportions are 90% red and 80% big.

If I *would* know the cell proportions I could use stratified sampling to - roughly speaking - increase the representativeness of my sample (compared to simple random sampling). But since I *don't* know those proportions I could only stratify on one characteristic. This might still leave me with a sample which is unrepresentative on the second characteristic (or in particular, for certain cells).

It seems to me that I should be able to use my knowledge of the marginal proportions** to improve upon the stratify-on-one-characteristic-only strategy, but like I said, I cannot come up with how.

Background: I'm looking at this problem for a work project where we aim to provide general advice for sampling. I'd be grateful for any pointers to relevant (scientific) literature, or a clear explanation of why I'm completely misguided.

`* and I believe they may be correlated but obviously I don't know what the correlation is, else I could estimate the cell proportions

** and not just in hindsight to check whether the sample ended up being representative for both characteristics separately

Comment: I don't really see what you are asking. as you say you are missing the information (correlation) to make a 2 dimensional sampling.  But then if you are missing the information than just guess a correlation... eg that they are independent.

Comment: Well, guessing a correlation (including 0) did occur to me, but any guess might be far off the correct value in realistic scenarios, in which case I might end up worse than with simple 1-dimensional sampling.

Comment: Thinking about it more, I guess the reason why this is not a problem that comes up in practice very often is that it's very unlikely that I *do* have a practical method to control which units I'm sampling if I *don't* have the full cell proportions: in the scenario in the question, how would I (randomly) sample a unit from the populations that is red and small given that I don't know how many small red units there are?